# Is there any database listing patent market price valuations?

Tags: valuation

If I want to know what the price of  a patents is (to sell, buy or understand the internal transfer price), where to find the data to support a market price valuation?

Based on comparable patents on the same business area, similar companies, and/or similar invention/devices.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I highly doubt there is any such database. Many and perhaps most patents are never sold.

Comment: True. Even though most of patents are never sold... they almost always are part of a company assets.... and as an asset, they have to go through a valuation process to be included in the Balance Sheet of the company...

Comment: How a company values any particular patent would probably be considered trade secret and not publicly available information.

Comment: You are right. I´ll open a new question regarding patent valuation (even if their valuation is considered a trade secret.... it they are part of a (publicly released) Balance sheet, their valuation will be known somehow...

Comment: I’m not aware of patents, in general, being listed on balance sheets. If a patent is licensed, then it generates income which if obviously reported. For some companies, this is a source of considerable income. For others and probably most companies, patents simply protect their products and the sale of those products are what is reported.

Comment: " A patent is a type of intangible asset because it lacks a physical form, outside of documentary evidence, but still has value to the business because it secures a legal monopoly for the owner. Because it is an asset, the patent must be included on a business’s balance sheet."  https://smallbusiness.chron.com/patent-impairment-balance-sheet-36820.html